# No Wifi adapter found after a reboot [ubuntu 18.04]

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

I have been using for a year now and today after a reboot it shows no wi-fi adapter found tried rebooting also tried updating noting works any solution for this ?

Some information about my device:

```
lspci -v | grep -i network
```

00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df0 (rev 30)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and also: `dmesg | grep iwl` and finally: `rfkill list all`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.